# How to get context for TimerTask in Service

Tags: android, android-service

I need to get `ComplexPreferences` within a `Service`

**Code**

```
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                sendRequestToServer();
            }

            private void sendRequestToServer() {

// How to get context here to initialize ctx ?

                        ComplexPreferences complexPreferences = 
ComplexPreferences.getComplexPreferences( ctx , "App_Settings", 0);

}
```

How to do it?

Full code of class

```
public class gps_service extends Service {

    private static final String TAG = "MyService";
    private LocationListener listener;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private Timer timer = new Timer();
    private  DLocation dLocation;
    private final Object lock = new Object();

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.i("LocalService", "Received start id " + startId + ": " + intent);
        // We want this service to continue running until it is explicitly
        // stopped, so return sticky.
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate(); 
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                sendRequestToServer();
            }

            private void sendRequestToServer() {

                synchronized (lock) {
                    try{

                        if(dLocation == null) return;

                        ComplexPreferences complexPreferences = ComplexPreferences.getComplexPreferences( context , "App_Settings", 0);
                        AppSettings appSettings = complexPreferences.getObject("App_Settings", AppSettings.class);
                        if(appSettings != null)
                        {

                        }

                        DLocation tempDL = dLocation;

                        LocationItem locationItem = new LocationItem();
                        locationItem.DeviceID = tempDL.DeviceID;
                        locationItem.Latitude = tempDL.Latitude;
                        locationItem.Longitude = tempDL.Longitude;
                        locationItem.TimeOfRequest = tempDL.TimeOfRequest;

                        Gson gson = new Gson();
                        String requestObject =  gson.toJson(locationItem);
                        String url = "http://XXXXXXX";

                        makeRequest(url, requestObject);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {

                    }
                }
            }
        }, 0, 1*60*1000); //1 Minutes
```

Comment: A `Service` is a `Context`. That is, use `this`, or `MyService.this`, e.g., as necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
ComplexPreferences complexPreferences = ComplexPreferences.getComplexPreferences( YourService.this , "App_Settings", 0);
```

Or this

```
Context context = this;
ComplexPreferences complexPreferences = ComplexPreferences.getComplexPreferences( context, "App_Settings", 0);
```

**EDIT**

```
public class gps_service extends Service {

    private static final String TAG = "MyService";
    private LocationListener listener;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private Timer timer = new Timer();
    private  DLocation dLocation;
    private final Object lock = new Object();
    Context context ;
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.i("LocalService", "Received start id " + startId + ": " + intent);
        // We want this service to continue running until it is explicitly
        // stopped, so return sticky.
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate(); 
        context = this;
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                sendRequestToServer();
            }

            private void sendRequestToServer() {

                synchronized (lock) {
                    try{

                        if(dLocation == null) return;

                        ComplexPreferences complexPreferences = ComplexPreferences.getComplexPreferences( context , "App_Settings", 0);
                        AppSettings appSettings = complexPreferences.getObject("App_Settings", AppSettings.class);
                        if(appSettings != null)
                        {

                        }

                        DLocation tempDL = dLocation;

                        LocationItem locationItem = new LocationItem();
                        locationItem.DeviceID = tempDL.DeviceID;
                        locationItem.Latitude = tempDL.Latitude;
                        locationItem.Longitude = tempDL.Longitude;
                        locationItem.TimeOfRequest = tempDL.TimeOfRequest;

                        Gson gson = new Gson();
                        String requestObject =  gson.toJson(locationItem);
                        String url = "http://XXXXXXX";

                        makeRequest(url, requestObject);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {

                    }
                }
            }
        }, 0, 1*60*1000); //1 Minutes
```

Comment: Hi! It does not work. It says Wrong 1st argument type. Found TimeTask but it should be android.content.Context. Have we pass context of Service to TimerTask as an argument?

Comment: @AcademyofProgrammer check updated ans

Comment: It says incopatible types. You solution does not work. Sorry.

Comment: Should we get context get before `imer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {`  and pass it somehow to TimerTask ?

Comment: @AcademyofProgrammer yup

Comment: Pls provide code how to do it so I can upvote, bro.

Comment: @AcademyofProgrammer share your service class with quetion

Comment: Done. Code is out there.

Comment: @AcademyofProgrammer check updated ans